# In Angular 7 how to load CSS of Arabic language (RTL) from English language (LTR)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am developing an application in Angular 7 using ngx-translate for internationalization and bootstrap based AdminLTE 3. 
I have two css:

1. One for LTR based languages
2. another for RTL based languages.

When I select Arabic language which is a RTL direction, how to load the bootstrap_rtl.css and unload the bootstrap_ltr.css.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-right">
    <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="useLanguage('en')">
      English
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="useLanguage('ar')">
      Arabic
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="useLanguage('ta')">
      Russian
    </a>
</div>
```

```html
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  useLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have a separate file for each style , do you use css variable  to control the styles ?

Comment: Can you provide the first 30 lines of each css LTR and RTL?

Answer (score 7):

you can create a key in the translation file as flage of the current theme if it's  `rtl` or `ltr` and this value will change base of the language that you have select

*style.scss*

```css
.ltr {
  @import 'themes/_en';
}

.rtl {
    @import 'themes/_ar';
}
```

_ar.json

```js
{
  "currentTheme":"rtl"
}
```

_en.json

```js
{
  "currentTheme":"ltr"
}
```

app.template

```html
<div  [ngClass]="'currentTheme' | translate">  // 
{{'currentTheme' | translate}}
<p class="base-align">
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

theme <button (click)="useLanguage('en')">English</button>
<button (click)="useLanguage('ar')">Arabic</button>
</div>
```

> when the languae change the value of currentTheme will chnage and the style will change

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfdrxr)